# JavaScript slideshow not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ecmascript-6

I have been working on my own JavaScript slideshow using jQuery 3.1.1. It works okay, but for some reason the transition animation isn't smooth. When there are only two photos, it works fine but once I add a third it doesn't work nicely at all.

I have made this fiddle, if someone could offer some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

```js
!function($) {
  "use strict";
  $.slideshow = function(container) {
    let $container = $(container);
    let children = $container.find('.slide').length;
    $container.find('.slide').each(function(index) {
      let zIndex = 210 - index;
      let bg = $(this).data('bg');
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
    });
    let settings = {
      'transition': 500,
      'delay': 6000,
    };
    let currentSlide = 0;
    $.fn.showNext = function() {
      let nextSlide = ((currentSlide + 1) < children) ? (currentSlide + 1) : 0;
      let $current = $container.find('.slide:nth-child(' + (currentSlide + 1) + ')');
      let $next = $container.find('.slide:nth-child(' + (nextSlide + 1) + ')');
      $current.animate({
        'opacity': 0
      }, settings.transition);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $current.css('z-index', 200);
        $current.css('opacity', 1);
        $next.css('z-index', 210);
      }, settings.transition + 100);
      console.log(currentSlide, nextSlide);
      currentSlide = ((currentSlide + 1) < children) ? (currentSlide + 1) : 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $container.showNext();
      }, settings.delay);
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
      $container.showNext();
    }, settings.delay);
  };
}(jQuery);

$.slideshow('.slideshow');
```

```css
    .slideshow-wrapper {
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .slideshow {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .slide {
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/4.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the jQuery code. Here is what I've discovered:

1. It's running into a race condition, where the JavaScript is running
   before than the HTML has had time to load. None of the initial div
   tags have been loaded into the document object yet. The container div
   has a length of 0. A single setTimeout with a 0ms load will unblock that & allow the HTML to load, before the JS runs.
2. The 3rd image (4.jpg) is being shown 1st, not the 1st image (6.jpg). The z-index is being changed in the code, but isn't being applied back to the images.
3. The opacity of "current" is being animated to 0 & then immediately bumped back up to 1. I think you're looking to change the opacity of "next" to 1, instead of "current" from 1 to 0 and then back to 1.
4. The initialization transitions start out smooth, but then the repeat animations tend to loop faster & fade out to a white page before the "next" image appears. Users may find that jolting that the animation starts with a 6 second delay & then speeds up to 1/2 seconds per image. That latter animation is too fast.
5. The animation was popping instead of dissolving. It's also not using a cross-dissolve, but I recommend using one. I've added it to show you how it works.
6. The code doesn't appear to be cleaned up, which is why you're running into coding issues with console.log & being forced to use $container to correct it. The container variable can't be redeclared with "let container = ..." after it's passed in as a parameter with (container). When I correct that by passing in a "selector" parameter name, then I can remove the $ on the container variables. This helps distinguish which code is tied to jQuery & which isn't.
7. There was a heavy reliance on using the setTimeout method, but as you probably already know... those only run 1x & then stop. To make them loop continuously, the starting setTimeout has been changed to setInterval.

Try out this [edited JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/09wj9w7x/), which fixes those issues. 
Btw, here is the jQuery [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

**CSS changes:**

1. Added "opacity: 0;" to all slides.
2. Added "opacity: 1;" to the 1st slide.

**CSS:**

```
.slideshow-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slideshow {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0; /* <-- New --- */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide:first-child { /* <-- New --- */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript has a lot of edits**

```
!function($) {
   "use strict";

   $.slideshow = function(selector) {
        let container = $(selector);
        let children = container.find('.slide').length;

        container.find('.slide').each(function(index) {
          let zIndex = 210 - index;
          $(this).css('z-index', zIndex); // <-- This was missing, as it was loading the last image as the 1st image.
          let bg = $(this).data('bg');
          $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
        });

        let settings = {
          'delay': 2000
        };

        let currentSlide = 0;

        $.fn.showNext = function() {
          let nextSlide = ((currentSlide + 1) < children) ? (currentSlide + 1) : 0;
          let current = container.find('.slide:nth-child(' + (currentSlide + 1) + ')');
          let next = container.find('.slide:nth-child(' + (nextSlide + 1) + ')');

          next.animate({
            'opacity': 1,
            'z-index': 210
          }, settings.transition);

          // Creates the Cross-Dissolve, as 1 image "next" is fadding up from opacity 0 to 1, while current is fadding down from 1 to 0.
          current.animate({
             'opacity': 0,
             'z-index': 200
          }, settings.transition);
       };

       // Starts the animation loop.
       setInterval(function() {
          container.showNext();
          currentSlide = ((currentSlide + 1) < children) ? (currentSlide + 1) : 0;
       }, settings.delay);
   };
}(jQuery);

setTimeout(function() {
   $.slideshow('.slideshow');
}, 0); // Fixes the race condition, by allowing the HTML to load before the JS runs.
```

**HTML - no changes, but remove the script tag when using jsfiddle**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/4.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have fun playing with the [edited JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/09wj9w7x/) to further customize it!

Comment: I really appreciate you looking at my code in depth. Using `setInteval` is definitely what I wanted instead of multiple timeouts. I think the snippet here is behaving somewhat differently than my actual product but what I ended up doing was getting the previous image and making its z-index lower than the next one in the queue with the transition; they were the same so it would show the wrong image sometimes. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! I've run into similar issues with slideshows before. Glad that I could help you out today!

Comment: "It's running into a race condition" -> Race conditions are impossible in Javascript due to its single-threaded nature. What you're describing is not waiting for a resource to be available before acting on it, the same as what would happen if you tried to open a file before it exists, browsing a drive before it's mounted, etc. In this case, the `setTimeout()` method should be avoided because there's no guarantee that the DOM will be ready on the next tick. You want to wrap the slideshow initializer in the `document.ready` event, like so: `$(function() { $.slideshow('.slideshow'); });`.

Comment: Race conditions are possible to create in Javascript, especially when working with Ajax. It's when multiple asynchronous non-blocking events are sent out in rapid succession & their callbacks are returned in the wrong order, than what the developer expects them to be returned. Once Ajax calls are sent to the server, there isn't a guarantee that each server-side service will be a rapid service. 3rd party server-side connectivity usually slows down services. With Ajax, we can see that race conditions do occur in Javascript, because we can see the console log reverse the order of the callbacks.

Comment: What I was describing in point 1... "where the JavaScript is running before than the HTML has had time to load"... was a race between JavaScript & the HTML DOM. The JavaScript initialization process was winning the race over the HTML loading process. This... "A single setTimeout with a 0ms" is an advanced trick & was used to illustrate the concept, but yes, your code is valid jQuery too. Did you know that the jQuery library uses the native JS `setTimeout()` method in its 2.1.4 & 3.1.1 library jquery.js files? It's in their jQuery.ready.promise() & ajax() methods + document.readyState code. :)

Comment: That's still not a race condition, that's an AJAX ordering issue. Because AJAX requests are asynchronous, you cannot guarantee the order that the callbacks will be invoked in. However, Javascript is single-threaded, so the callbacks will always be invoked in sequence, but never simultaneously. This means that it's impossible for a race condition to occur. Don't confuse 'I don't know the order of the callbacks' with 'race condition'. They mean two totally different things. Not knowing the callback order is the same as providing two buttons and not knowing which one the user will click on first.

Comment: Also, `setTimeout()` in jQuery's code is used as a fallback for IE 9 and 10 when the DOMContentLoaded event fires before the JS code for jQuery is finished parsing. So yes, it does use it, as a **workaround** for incorrect browser behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue lies here

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $current.css('z-index', 200);
        $current.css('opacity', 1); // this should be $next.css('opacity', 1);
        $next.css('z-index', 210);
      }
```

You should also try to get rid of the 3 setTimeout(), they look redundant.
You can use setInteval() for changing the image. Change the css properties in the completion call back of the animate and you can git rid of another setTimeout().

Check this :

```js
!function($) {
  "use strict";
  $.slideshow = function(container) {
    let $container = $(container);
    let children = $container.find('.slide').length;
    $container.find('.slide').each(function(index) {
      let zIndex = 210 - index;
      let bg = $(this).data('bg');
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
    });
    let settings = {
      'transition': 500,
      'delay': 6000,
    };
    let currentSlide = 0;
     $.fn.showNext = function() {
      let nextSlide = ((currentSlide + 1) < children) ? (currentSlide + 1) : 0;
      let $current = $container.find('.slide:nth-child(' + (currentSlide + 1) + ')');
      let $next = $container.find('.slide:nth-child(' + (nextSlide + 1) + ')');
      $current.animate({
        'opacity': 0
      }, settings.transition,function(){
      
        $current.css('z-index', 200);
        $next.css('opacity', 1);
        $next.css('z-index', 210);
      
      });
      currentSlide = ((currentSlide + 1) < children) ? (currentSlide + 1) : 0;
    };
    setInterval(function() {
      $container.showNext();
    }, settings.delay);
  };
}(jQuery);

$.slideshow('.slideshow');
```

```css
.slideshow-wrapper {
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .slideshow {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .slide {
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide" data-bg="https://s3.amazonaws.com/StartupStockPhotos/uploads/20160503/4.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```